# Create custom template tag

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I have a model that has a method which needs a parameter (the request.user.some_field) to do the job.
So, to send this request.user, I've created a template tag.

**extra_tag.py**

```
from django import template

register = template.library()

@register.simple_tag
def precio(sub_medida, tipo_usuario):
    return sub_medida.precio_venta(tipo_usuario)
```

and when i go to the template where is loaded, I get the following error:
on template: 'module' object is not callable

on console: "../../extra_tag.py", line 3, in 
    register = template.library()

I don't know if this helps, but i followed this documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Thanks in advance..

Comment: change `template.library()` to `template.Library()`

Comment: I don't know what to say. Thanks..